# Could not find a *-tests.jar file in the *root* of your test package

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am getting this error while uploading the test package on AWS farm. i.e.:

```
There was a problem processing your file. We could not find a *-tests.jar file in the *root* of your test package.
```

However, jars are available in the zip file.  I have set up my code as per the given instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html

Below are the plugins which I have used in POM.xml :

```maven
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>3.3.0</version>

            <executions>

                <execution>

                    <phase>package</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>single</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>

                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                        <descriptors>

                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>

                        </descriptors>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it's not enough to have jars in your zip file. Check if you have jar with specific name `*-tests.jar` , like `myservice-tests.jar`. Probably it has to be in the root of the archive.